# Changing state specific mxml parts in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flex4, mxml, states

I'm using something like this in my MXML file:

`<s:label id='mxml_label' text.state1='test' text.state2='test 2' />`

Now i would like to change the state1 text from as3 on runtime.

Anyone any suggestions?

thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind the text for state1 to a bindable string variable that you will then update whenever you want.

```
[Bindable] private var state1TextString:String = "test";
```

Then your expression becomes :

```
text.state1="{state1TextString}"
```

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for this first accepted answer :) For more information on binding you can try the Tour de Flex application that comes with a lot of samples for common situations.

Comment: Sure, it did just that what i was looking for :). But perhaps you can tell me how this would work if i use it on mx:Label and htmlText, formatting gets lost if i use bindable vars. any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "formatting gets lost". If you speak about styleNames from a css file, this is a problem I have encountered too, but i have not found a solution yet.

Comment: formatting, at first it is **test**, after the update the var, it reads `<b>test</b>`, so the html text is shown, instead of, in this case, bold text.

Comment: `<mx:Label htmlText='<b>Test</b>' />` shows **Test**  
`<mx:Label htmlText='{variable}' />` shows <b>Test</b>

Comment: @Wilfred Did the first code snippet work ? According to [this link](http://help.adobe.com/fr_FR/AS3LCR/Flex_4.0/mx/controls/Label.html#htmlText) i should not. Anyway I am afraid I have no relevant answer to your question.

Comment: Well it all works great, i just made a mistake, above snippet works perfect. thx for your time ;)

Comment: and to explain what was wrong.. i used &gt; and &lt; in the mxml source to get > and <, this won't be necessary if you change htmlText in AS3.. :)